# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar correctamente el estado global en Zustand en un proyecto de Astro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

En mi proyecto de Astro, tengo configuradas tres páginas diferentes, y cada una tiene asignada su propia canción. Cuando se navega de una página a otra, se detiene la canción que estaba sonando y comienza a reproducirse la nueva canción asignada a la página a la que se ha accedido. Para controlar la reproducción del audio, he creado un botón usando React; al presionarlo una vez, se pausa la canción que está sonando, y si se presiona de nuevo, la canción se reanuda.

El sistema está diseñado para que, si una canción está sonando y el usuario cambia de página, el audio que estaba reproduciéndose se pausa automáticamente y empieza a sonar la canción correspondiente a la nueva página. Hasta aquí, todo funciona correctamente.

Sin embargo, he encontrado un problema. Después de haber navegado por todas las páginas y querer regresar a alguna de ellas, el mecanismo deja de funcionar correctamente. Estoy utilizando una herramienta llamada Zustand para almacenar de manera global el nombre de la canción que debe reproducirse en cada página. Solo que, parece ser que hay un problema, ya que solo me permite guardar el nombre de la canción una vez por página, lo cual podría estar relacionado con el fallo que experimento al intentar navegar de nuevo entre las páginas.

este es el componente ButtonPlayAudio.jsx que está en el layout

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { usePlayerStore } from "../store/playerStore"
import "../styles/buttonplaystyle.css"

import {
    URL_SONG_CP,
    URL_SONG_ER,
    URL_SONG_PL,
} from "../constants/urls.js";


const ButtonPlayAudio = () => {

    const [audioCP] = useState(typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio(URL_SONG_CP));
    const [audioER] = useState(typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio(URL_SONG_ER));
    const [audioPL] = useState(typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio(URL_SONG_PL));
    const { currentMusic, isPlaying, setIsPlaying } = usePlayerStore(state => state)

    useEffect(() => {
        isPlaying
            ? playAudio(currentMusic)
            : pauseAudio()
    }, [isPlaying, currentMusic])

    const playAudio = (currentMusic) => {
        pauseOtherAudios(currentMusic)
        switch (currentMusic) {
            case "cp":
                audioCP.play()
                break;
            case "er":
                audioER.play()
                break;
            case "pl":
                audioPL.play()
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    const pauseAudio = () => {
        audioCP.pause()
        audioER.pause()
        audioPL.pause()
    }

    const pauseOtherAudios = (currentMusic) => {
        switch (currentMusic) {
            case "cp":
                audioER.pause()
                audioPL.pause()
                break;
            case "er":
                audioCP.pause()
                audioPL.pause()
                break;
            case "ph":
                audioCP.pause()
                audioER.pause()
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(currentMusic);
        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
    }


    return (
        <div className="btn-play-audio glitch-container" onClick={handleClick}>
            <a>
                <div className="flex flex-row">
                    Ambient Audio &nbsp;
                    {!isPlaying ? <img
                        className="play-icon"
                        src="/icons/play-icon.svg"
                        alt="play"
                        id="btn-play"
                    /> : <img
                        className="pause-icon"
                        src="/icons/pause-icon.svg"
                        alt="pause"
                        id="btn-pause"
                    />}


                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ButtonPlayAudio;
```

este es usePlayerStore con zustand

```
import { create } from "zustand";


export const usePlayerStore = create((set) => ({
    isPlaying: false,
    currentMusic: "cp",
    setIsPlaying: (isPlaying) => set({ isPlaying }),
    setCurrentMusic: (currentMusic) => set({ currentMusic }),
}))
```

este es la pagina 1 pageCP.astro

```
<SectionCP />
<script>
    import { usePlayerStore } from "../store/playerStore.js";

    usePlayerStore.setState({
        currentMusic: "cp",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yo intentaría agregar `currentMusic` a la lista de dependencias del `useEffect` para empezar, solo tienes `isPlaying` y según la lógica que describes también `currentMusic` cambia en cada re-render.